# Bootstrap assets only load when putting the assets folder in public folder

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm starting to build a react project that includes bootstrap.

I am using an assets folder from BootstrapMade.com

the bootstrap works find when I copy the assets folder inside the public directory and include the js files in my index.html using:

```
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

But, when I copy the assets folder to the src folder and try to include the js files in my index.html using:

```
  <script src="../src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The bootstrap won't work. and I've been told that it's not advisable to put the assets folder in the public directory.

I am using create-react-app with vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need ES modules for this 
check more on ES modules here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/ecma-script-modules/

Webpack server does not serve the content from inside `src`. It only bundles them. So you cannot use `<script src="path_to_src">` to access its contents. But `<script src="path_to_public">` can be used for `public` directory because contents of `public` are served as static assets by webpack dev server.

Comment: Thanks! what are the cons of putting the assets folder inside the public folder?

Comment: I'd recommend avoid putting js assets inside public folder if possible, images and other static assets are fine, but you can always `npm install` the library you need from `npm` registry if its available.